# Calculating in TextMate using "Filter Through Command"

Tags: textmate, calculator

I have a line in a file, which I have open in TextMate. I would like to select the line, or rather the content of the line; `54 + 34.43` and have it be replaced with the total sum.

I've used the "Filter Through Command" dialog which gives me access to CLI tools. I figure this would also be useful here, but I cannot simply pass off the equation to `bc`.

Any pointers? Perhaps via python? I'd like to be able to use Filter Through Command and avoid taking on some sort of Bundle to accomplish this.

Comment: Several scripting bundles support *evaluate current line* or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "Math" bundle, I think it's active by default.

With your expression selected hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to open a contextual menu with a bunch of number-related operations.

```
--EDIT 1--
```

I didn't read your question correctly. [Here is a page](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9891) which helped me a lot while looking for a quick way to do some math on the CLI.

In short, write a very short shell script wrapped around `bc`, make it executable, put it in your path and call it via TextMate's *Filter Through Command*.

```
--EDIT 2--
```

While a shell script might be more portable and reusable and the "Math" bundle might be a little more versatile the *ad hoc* command you need is `echo "$TM_SELECTED_TEXT" | bc`. It will be remembered by TextMate and shown as default command next time you hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>.